# I have problems with my codeigniter webapp it works fine on my local host but not on live server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, web-applications, routes

Can any one help me?

I code a web app in php with codeigniter 
it works well on my localhost but when I upload it on live server it loads only home page. For other pages it gives a error 
''No input file specificed''

When I do google about it. 
There are many tricks like change .htaccess but no one works.

What should I do

Check this 
It loads foodpark.tk

But does not load
Foodpark.tk/category/index
And all the other pages

this is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Options -Indexes
```

i also tried to put a question mark after index.php in .htaccess but it gives 404 error from hosting

Sorry for my poor english

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled (assuming you're using an Apache environment)? Is Allow Override enabled (for actually using the htaccess file)?

Comment: @FabFuerste how can I check it
I am on share hosting
I think it is since it load my homepage perfectly

Comment: The rewrite part only applies with everything "after" the root path. When you put a simple "phpinfo()" in the index.php, does it include "rewrite" somewhere?

Comment: @FabFuerste how can I enable it. If I am on shared hosting

Comment: Page is working with `index.php` file included. Show your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @tpojka question is updated with .htaccess check

Comment: Make sure your controllers, models etc filenames and classes start where only the first letter is upper case rest lowercase. Explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: @akash kumar: I still assume that mod_rewrite might be off (since it works locally). In your app directory, go to "public" folder, open index.php file and add 

phpinfo();

at the top. Then upload it to your hoster and reload your page. Now use search function to find the term "rewrite".

Comment: Is that part or all of `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

In your .htaccess file Change

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

To

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in .htaccess. This is from my working project. Hope you are using godaddy server.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```